# Problem with jdk and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Let me start by saying I've been doing professional development work in C++ for about 15 years, and I've done a very small amount of Java on Linux systems.  However, I seem to be doing something incorrectly with my Java installation on eclipse.

I have eclipse installed on a Windows 7 machine in C:\tools\eclipse\helios.
I have the Java jdk installed in C:\tools\Java\jdk1.6.0.
The Java jre is installed in C:\tools\Java\jre1.6.0.

In eclipse, I create a java project, and point the project at the jdk folder listed above.  In other words, I have the jdk listed as one of the installed JREs and it is the selected JRE.

BTW: I also have Google's android tools and the MotoDev envioronment installed in eclipse, and I can write and build android java code in those projects.  Of course, they don't use the jdk.

So, I'm relatively new to Java and I want to start simple, so I created the basic HelloWorld project. I have the following simple code:

```
package app;

import system;  // System not recognized here!!!

public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        system.out.println("Hello World!");  // System not recognized here, obviously!
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  There doesn't seem to be anywhere to point to the jdk/lib directory.  The jdk looks in jdk1.6.0/jre/lib, which I'm pretty sure isn't going to help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System class is present in `java.lang` package. It's imported by default. So no need to import it like you did. Please bear in mind that it's Java's convention to have class names begin with uppercase characters. Hence System class is with upper case S

Documentation for packages and classes in JDK is available at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. It's a good idea to refer to this often especially when beginning with Java programming

Comment: Thank you all for that.  I did try to use a capital S as well, but apparently only on the import statement.  When I removed the import and capitalized the System, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a capital 'S' for System? And you shouldn't need to import 'System'. It is imported automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It is `System` and not `system`. And No need to import it explicitly.